# No xelzd - Cannot find xeldz in all drives. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

Tags: windows, windows-7, boot, license-key, bcdedit

Today my windows 7, after download a not-so-secure file (a good prank from an University friend to show me that the SO is really outdated), the windows license was deleted. (I have a buyed license, and a genuine disk, I promise). I laugh after see that, so I clicked on "Activate Windows online now", put my license, all correct, restarted the machine to delete the "this copy of windows is not genuine" message, and KABOOM.

"No xelzd" message at the start. The windows doesn't start. This is the message:

```
no xelzd
no xelzd
no xelzd

no xelzd

BIOS: Drive=0x0 H=0, S=0

Cannot find xeldz in all drives. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart.
```

[no xelzd error message photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Jjg.png)

How to solve this? (I'll answer my self in few minutes)

Comment: Well, the demonstration was effective. Ask your [ex] friend. xelzd is an activation hacker/remover. I think it's a bcdedit parameter that's been changed. I don't know how to reset it…. hope someone does...

Comment: thanks @Tetsujin but I posted my own answer: I am using my restored win7 right now. But thanks to clarify me that xeldz is part of windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I though my pc was destroyed, so I check if the BIOS and the physical disk are still there (yes, a good thing), starting the machine and opening the BIOS window pushing F2 key continously. My Gigabyte BIOS was telling me all was OK with the hardware (the boot order show me my 2 physical disks correctly)

Researching a bit over internet I found a way to solve the problem, so I used my Win7 disk on the Cd reader... but it doesn't boot after changing the order in the BIOS. (yes, Murphy's law). So I downloaded a Win7 copy from Microsoft webpage, using my license.

I got another PC, downloaded [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) portable version, put a 16GB USB on the first port, downloaded the win7 copy, and I created my Win7 bootable USB. (REMEMBER TO CHANGE: "TARGET SYSTEM" from UEFI to BIOS/EFI if you don't have a UEFI version of windows installed on your broken machine. Don't waste your time, like me)

After that, I put my USB on my machine and started it again. Usual windows installation:

- select language. time and keyboard -> next
- DO NOT CLICK on Install now button
- click on "REPAIR YOUR COMPUTER" button
- the system will start search your SO on the disks
- if it found any, it will show it for you on a list
- if not, they show you an empty list (this was my case)
- there are 2 options in the window, use the first option
- a window called "System Recovery Options" will appear
- select "Command Promt" option

A cmd window will appear, on the location X:\sources\ > (virtual location created by mounting on ram your USB operative system)

Well, now you have a cmd, the very first thing is to check if you still have your disk:

- write ***diskpart***, click enter
- the command promt (the X:\sources\ part) will change to DISKPART>
- write ***list volume***, click enter
- you will see your logical disks (c:, d:, etc)
- or not (my case) and here you have 2 options:
- the list shows you an empty volume list -> reinstall your windows (very rare, maybe anyone give you another option here)
- the list shows you your partitions but without letters (my case) so you have luck
- write ***list disk***, click enter
- write ***select disk #***, click enter (where # is the number of your physical disk that has the windows installed on, if you reach here, with the letter deleted/changed)
- write ***detail disk***, click enter (to see partitions)
- write ***select volume #***, click enter (where # is the number of the volume(partition) you have your windows installed)
- write ***assing letter=x***, click enter (where x is the old letter of your windows disk: take care to free that letter changing all letters of the other volumes because you cannot have 2 volumes with the same letter)
- write ***EXIT***, click enter (to leave diskpart)

Well now you have your disk, it's time to delete that annoying file (maybe you don't need to do that). You can use DIR command to reach your download folder: mine is the desktop so I wrote:

- ***dir c:\Users\user\Desktop***, click enter (to get the name of the file)
- ***cd c:\Users\user\Desktop***, click enter (to reach the folder)
- ***del /f nameoffile.ext***, click enter (to delete the file)

Now the last part:

- write ***bcdedit /enum***, click enter (if you get an error here, check your UEFI/not UEFI windows version and which version you installed on the USB)
- write ***bcdedit /default***, click enter {xxxxxx-xxxxx-xx-xx} (change the xxxx with the id you get with the enum command)

Now shutdown your computer, remove the USB, restore the BIOS boot order, and restart the machine. Windows must load again and you can use your license number correctly.

Comment: If a 'friend' did that to me, two things would happen: (1) they would cease to be a friend (2) they would get a savage beating.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey maybe that (2) is a very good option: I lost 3 sleep hours to get this solution...